# The information which process path to choose - readout of token or BPMN-elements (e.g. task)

Tags: bpmn

I'm new to BPMN and I'm a little confused how the decision of a token is made which path the token should take now.

In my sources I found two statements

1. The now processed BPMN element (e.g. gateway) fetches its needed information (for making a decision which path direction to use) **from the already processed path-elements**

   - It goes downstream until, the needed information is given
   - This information is reached through a task or a gateway or ... (downstream or anywhere in the process)
2. The now processed BPMN element (e.g. gateway) fetches its needed information (for making a decision which path direction to use) **from the token itself**

   - Every BPMN-element writes some information in the token, so that the upstream BPMN-elements get the needed information directly from the token

To be not that abstract a little example (see screenshot)

- State 1:

  - In the task "determine variant" it is chosen *variant A with subvariant 1* and *variant B*
  - The token now arrives at the BPMN-element *inclusive gateway*
  - Question: The information what to do now is out of the BPMN-element task (determine variant) **or** the token itself
- State 2:

  - The blue token arrives at the BPMN-element *exclusive gateway*
  - Question: The information what to do now is out of BPMN-elements (inclusive gateway and (if necessary) task: determine variant) **or** the token itself
- State 3:

  - The grey token arrives at the BPMN-element *joining inclusive gateway*
  - Question: The information what to do now is out of BPMN-elements (downstream: task: doing things with variant B and (if necessary) inclusive gateway and (if necessary) task: determine variant; additionally: exclusive gateway) **or** the token itself

[image: Example process]

So as you can imagine my question is if the information (which process branch to go) is out of

- the BPMN-elements **or**
- the token itself.

Many thanks in advance for your help!